# while until condition doesn´t work

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements, infinite-loop

i want to write a little program, but don´t know why my loop isn´t working correctly.

```
while ((!ss.legal(myNumbers, colRand, rowRand, numRand)) || (triedNumbers.size() != 9)) {   
                System.out.println(triedNumbers.size());
//              if(triedNumbers.size()==9) break;
                numRand = getRandomNumber(1,9);
                if (!triedNumbers.contains(Integer.valueOf(numRand))) {
                    triedNumbers.add(Integer.valueOf(numRand));
                }

            }
```

The thing is the second condition. My syso-command tells me the size is already 9 but the loop doesn´t end?

If the random number is fine the legal method returns `true`. So the loop should end. If the size of the map gets 9, it should also end the loop because I am only checking the numbers from 1 to 9.

Comment: maybe you should use && instead of ||

Comment: There is no context to the code you've provided, so it's really hard to see what's going on.

Comment: If size is 9, your other condition must be returning true.

Comment: If the first condition is `true`, the second condition does not get evaluated, since you used `||`. Even if it would get evaulated (by using `|`), it would not change the result. or-ing something with `false` will yield the original value.

Comment: Maybe you should [get yourself acquainted with basic logic](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/CAL/digital-logic/gatesfunc/#orgate).

Comment: i'm sorry. It should do the first or the second one. If the number is ok, the legal-method gets -> true, and if the size of my Map is 9 it should break the loop .

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @ProgrammerGermany123 this pretty much describes the behaviour of `&&`. Please follow @px06's advice and get familiarized with basic logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `||` (or) with `&&` (and). As it is even if the size is already 9 the loop will still continue as long as the first condition is true